# DEbug x64 application using IDA PRO 6.1

Tags: debugging, 64-bit, reverse-engineering, ida, bochs

I have IDA PRO 6.1 - (i am unable to install the latest version)

I am trying to debug x64 application with bochs debugger or windgb.

I did the following:

1. installed Bochs-2.4.6
2. Installed both x86&x64 version of the windows debugger.
3. Made sure the default path to the debugger for Windows in ida.cfg is pouting to:

   ```
   DBGTOOLS = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\8.1\\Debuggers\\x86\\";
   ```

I cannot ebug x64 with any debugger and i would appreciate a little guidance as to the right way to configure the debuggers.

I am unable to debug any x64 application.
When i set the debugger to **bochs** it starts running and then gets stuck with errors like:

[image]

When I try to use **windgb** it keeps reporting that:

> Could not initialize WinDgb engine...with error: The specified procedure could not be found.(000007F)...

When i click OK I get:

> "The File can't be loaded by the debugger plugin. Please verify that the parameters are valid."

What are the right parameters?

Is there a connection string when I am debugging a local application. In the IDA help files it says to leave the Connection string empty for local application, but even when I select the x64 dbgsrv.exe and set the default connection string is does not work.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem, adding the windbg x86 location to the `PATH` environment variable solved the issue for me:

```
PATH = %PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x86
```

Comment: i'll give it a try.
Is it the User or System variables you added it to?

Comment: Yes it worked. Keep in mind though that IDA Pro has 2 configurations: one for standard Windows user and another one for admin user.

Comment: When debugging a x64 application you have to connect to the x64-dbgserver (C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\dbgsrv.exe) with the x86-debugger.